# Header shows gradient border

Tags: wordpress

My header doesnt show fixed can anyone tell me how to remove this black/and/white on the header here is the

[image: screenshot]
here is the link too  WEB [LINK](http://scottstaverna-ks.com)

Here is the code for header gradient

```
    .enable_fixhead .bliccaThemes-header.off-sticky { 

background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);

}
```

Comment: You are supposed to provide some more details. Your code or URL. Just an screenshot is not enough

Comment: Here is the link  scottstaverna-ks.com

Comment: It is a header border or something that i cannot remove it...

Comment: Anyone that can handle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
background: transparent;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,0) 78%);
```

with solid color e.g. black:

```
    background: #000;
```

So your new code will be:

```
.enable_fixhead .bliccaThemes-header.off-sticky {
    background: #000; /* use your preferred color */
}
```

> File:
>   http://scottstaverna-ks.com/wp-content/themes/sevill/css/main.css
>
> Line: 239

**Edit:**

You would also like to tweak Sticky header code as follows:

```
.disable-sticky .bliccaThemes-header.on-sticky,
.enable_fixhead.disable_sticky .bliccaThemes-header.on-sticky {
    position: fixed;
    opacity: 0.8; /* changed from 0 to 0.8 */
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -moz-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    -o-transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    transition: all 800ms cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000);
    background: #000;  /* added solid black color */
}
```

> File:
>   http://scottstaverna-ks.com/wp-content/themes/sevill/css/main.css
>
> Line: 238

Comment: Still have the same issue

Comment: You can do it by keeping `background: transparent;` and remove the other 3 lines. It will make the header background transparent. Keep in mind that your menu items and logo is in white color, therefore, they will not visible because of the transparent background.

Comment: Yess that is what i done but still have a white border on the header

Comment: There is no white border at my end. Try to remove the gradients from main.css while keeping the .`background: transparent;` code. Menu items are still in white color and invisible.

Comment: @X-Developer this is not the white border. as your images is under the header that showing white

Comment: Okay i want to remove that gradient or image whatever i cannot find it in CSS any image the gradient yes

Comment: @X-Developer .enable_fixhead .bliccaThemes-header.off-sticky remove thier gradient and add color according to your own choice

Comment: Yess know i have make it black bcuz i cannot remove it!

Comment: This top white space is coming from the page builder row containing the slider revolution. `min-height: 100vh;` is set for that row. Try to remove that property and see the effect.
See the screenshot for better understanding: https://i.imgur.com/MqVUqPY.png